# Simple xml php array wildcard

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

Can you advise what the array wildcard is for simple xml in php. I am wanting to get a wildcard response from the second part of the array. It will only work when the error is populated with a number, what is the wildcard so it will bring back all errors in the stuff array 0.

Example

```
$xml->Test->Account->Information->Stuff[0]->Next->Next->Error[]['Duration'];
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$results = array();
foreach ($xml->Test->Account->Information->Stuff[0]->Next->Next->Error as $error) {
    $results[] = $error['Duration'];
}
```

Comment: Hi. What I mean is the Error[] is usually Error[1] or whatever number is chosen for the array. I want the wildcard value for the [] as I have tried * however this does not seem to work.

Comment: So I am looking at the first record from Stuff[0] and then want to get all the errors that occur within that, so instead of having Error[0],Error[1] etc, I just want to put a wildcard in [].

Comment: That's the behavior my code intends to provide. The only other way I know is to use `$xml->xpath('//Test/Account/Information/Stuff[1]/Next/Next/Error[@Duration]')`